# Coveo Cloud Not Registering Analytics when Running In Live Mode

Tags: coveo

We are not seeing analytics passed through to Coveo Cloud when we run site in "live" mode.  Where the database is set to "master" rather than "web".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the `Coveo.SearchProvider.config` and look for the `coveoanalytics` tag. check the database attribute and check it's set to master like this:

```xml
<site patch:before="*[1]" name="coveoanalytics" virtualFolder="/coveo/rest/v6/analytics" enableTracking="true" database="master" domain="extranet" />
```

You can patch it on the `Coveo.SearchProvider.Custom.config` file if you don't want to edit the `Coveo.SearchProvider.config` file which I recommend you do this way.

Comment: Thanks but I'm actually looking to do the exact opposite of that.  The default has it looking at web and i want it looking at master.  I'm hesitant to update this file directly.  Can I just add another config file that executes after these and replaces that patch with the one I want.
    <site patch:instead="*[@name='coveoanalytics']" name="coveoanalytics" virtualFolder="/coveo/rest/v6/analytics" enableTracking="true" database="master" domain="extranet" />

Comment: in this case you can just change that entry to master instead of web. that will allow you to test whether the data is being sent or not. 
you can patch that later if you want. I've done this and it works :)

Comment: I will update my original answer to reflect the opposite then

Comment: Thanks I can't figure out how to make my code snipt show up nice like yours.  I now see in the network panel SItecore call the analytics but i still don't see any anlytics showing up in Coveo is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: if you are sending data through queries being made, I know it needs to have for the same term 10 new sessions executing the same query and it takes 24 hours to update the cloud if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @Diego, the minimum of 10 sessions with same term is only for Coveo Reveal to be able to build a model for query suggestion. Coveo Usage Analytics events are normally available in the reports withing 15 minutes from the action time.